# Code to replace SWF with HTML5 if no flash detected

Tags: html, wordpress, flash, embed

## What I have:

I'm embedding a *.swf file in a page.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="960" height="630" id="test1"> 

<param name="movie" value="demo.swf" />

<embed src="demo.swf" width="960" height="630" name="test1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

</object>
```

## What I need:

When flash is not detected, I need to display a HTML5 version of the *.swf file (made using Google Swiffy).

The HTML5 version is a large block of code in `<script></script>` tags.

## My question:

How do I detect if flash is not enabled and then substitute a *.swf with a HTML5 alternative?

I can't deviate from the above *.swf embed code because it's the only block of code that I can find that allows me to successfully embed *.swf files in WordPress posts.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I used [swfobject](http://learnswfobject.com/) for all web flash related project and by default you setup an alternate content div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a jQuery script to detect Flash support:

http://code.google.com/p/jqplugin/

If flash support isn't detected, the script hides the div containing the flash content and reveals the HTML5 version (or whatever your alternative content is).

Answer (score 0):

If you put your alternate code inside of your object tag, if a browser does not support that object (your swf) then it will instead only see the code.  This is how adobe checks for flash support and if it isn't supported shows the get flash button.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="960" height="630" id="test1"> 

    <param name="movie" value="demo.swf" />

    <embed src="demo.swf" width="960" height="630" name="test1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

    <!-- PUT YOUR WEBSITE CODE HERE-->

</object>
```